# Swift Crash: function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed>

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

On my crash report I get the following output at the top.

```
0x00000001001a6c80 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of 
Test.MMCheckUserDetailsController.submitOrderButtonTapped 
(Test.MMCheckUserDetailsController)() -> () (MMCheckUserDetailsController.swift:167)
```

Here is the code for this output:

```
  func submitOrderButtonTapped() {

  (L167) let roomNumberText = count(roomNumberTextField.text) > 0 ? roomNumberTextField.text : "0"
  (L168) var myRoomNumber: Int32 = Int32(roomNumberText.toInt()!)

    ...
  }
```

I do not see how this line can crash my app.

**What does this error actually means?**

Comment: May be I myself was not able to reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are use coalescing operator at Line Number 167 as below. and Try now.

```
let roomNumberText = roomNumberTextField.text ?? "0"
```

Comment: But you see my code. There is no array. How could I prevent this error?

Comment: yes, In my code 76 line have no array, it have facebook function. but last i solve with array.

Comment: using this got symbolicating : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: I still do not get what you mean?

Comment: A class where crash apps, in which array value may be changed

Comment: according to L167, click on Button after app Crash, Am i Right.

Comment: But I have still no idea where to search?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89664/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-confile).

Comment: @KiritModi not Working:)

Comment: @kirtimali your other issue, may be array issue.